# Generated clock constraints in vivado

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, vivado

I created my own clock since I need a 2Mhz clock and the clock generator IP wont let me go bellow 6Mhz.  I created a clock divider module.

```
module clock_divider#(parameter HALF_CYCLE_COUNT = 128, COUNT_BITS = 8)
(
    input clk_in,
    output reg clk_out = 1'b0
);

    reg [COUNT_BITS - 1:0] counter = 1'b0;
    always @(posedge clk_in) begin
        if(counter == HALF_CYCLE_COUNT - 1) begin
            counter <= 0;
            clk_out = ~clk_out;
        end else counter <= counter + 1;
    end
endmodule
```

Here is my top level module.

```
module audio_visualizer
(
    input clk,
    input m_data,
    output m_clk,
    output reg m_lr = 1'b1
);

    wire pdm_clk;
    clock_divider#(.HALF_CYCLE_COUNT(100), .COUNT_BITS(7)) pdm_clk_div(clk, pdm_clk);
    assign m_clk = pdm_clk;

    wire [7:0] sample;
    wire sample_changed;
    sampler s(pdm_clk, m_data, 1'b0, sample, sample_changed);

    ila_0 i(clk, sample, sample_changed, pdm_clk);
endmodule
```

I want to declare a constraint so that vivado knows the frequency of pdm_clk.  Here is what I have right now for clocking constraints.

```
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E3    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { clk }]; #IO_L12P_T1_MRCC_35 Sch=clk100mhz
create_clock -add -name clk -period 10.00 -waveform {0 5} [get_ports {clk}];
create_generated_clock -name pdm_clk -source [get_ports clk] -divide_by 50 [get_ports pdm_clk]
```

I keep getting this error.

```
[Vivado 12-1387] No valid object(s) found for create_generated_clock constraint with option '-objects [get_ports pdm_clk]'. ["/home/chase/vivado-workspace/Sound/Sound.srcs/constrs_1/imports/Desktop/Nexys4DDR_Master.xdc":9]
```

I am not sure how to tell vivado what the output of the generated clock is.  I have also tried `[get_pins audio_visualizer/pdm_clk]`.

Comment: I'm not sure I would be too concerned about anything at 2 MHz.  I would recommend using your divider as a chip enable and continue using the original clock.  My 2 cents

Comment: Good to know.  I just want to know how to set the constraint for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `pdm_clk` isn't a port, it's a wire, and so won't be found by the `get_ports` search.

What you should instead do, is target the actual register driving the signal. You can do this with something like (haven't checked):

```
create_generated_clock ... {pdm_clk_div|clk_out}
```

Where in this case `clk_out` is the name of the register inside the ```pdm_clk_div` instance which is driving the clock net.

If the above doesn't work, you can try something like `[get_pins {pdm_clk_div|clk_out}]` or `[get_registers {pdm_clk_div|clk_out}]`

---

As a side note, if you are generating your own clocks, you should also include a `BUFG` primitive on the output so that the clock can be promoted to the global clock network. This will avoid excessive skew warnings later on during fitting.

However I agree with @johnnymopo's comment that the best approach is to use the original clock to drive your registers and then use the clock divider to generate a clock enable. Instead of generated clock constraints in this case you may instead require multicycle paths to declared if there are any timing issues.

Comment: Wouldn't I also need to add the instance name somewhere since I can have two instances creating different frequencies.

Comment: @chasep255 ```pdm_clk_div``` was the instance name. ```clk_out``` is the output register of that instance. Say you had another instance called ```another_clk_div```, then the second constraint would target ```another_clk_div|clk_out```